# Loading an img object with a src in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, getelementbyid, getjson, src

I want to add a thumbnail picture to a book's details, derived from the google books api, on the webpage.  The code below will place the source code (api) for the appropriate book, first into the text field bookCover and then into the var copyPic, and then it should be copied into imgDisp, but it doesn’t.  I can see that bookCover holds the right text, and have checked that copyPic holds the correct content.

```
<img id="imgDisp" src="http://books.google.com/books/content? 
id=YIx0ngEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api" width="85" height="110"" />

$.getJSON(googleAPI, function(response) {
    $("#title").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.title);
    $("#subtitle").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.subtitle);
    $("#author").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.authors[0]);
    $("#description").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.description);
    $("#version").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.contentVersion);
    $("#modeR").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.readingModes.text);
    $("#bookCover").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);

    var copyPic = document.getElementById('bookCover').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("imgDisp").src=copyPic;
```

Does anyone know why not? Or can I put the api details directly into imgDisp (can’t find such code syntax anywhere on the net)?  Everything else is working fine. If I put a src in directly, then it works e.g.

```
document.getElementById("imgDisp").src = “http://.....api”
```

but not with a variable.

Comment: Just going by the formatting colouring on your code, I can see that there is a spare `"` at the end of the IMG tag - try removing that first.

Comment: quite right. A result of me moving things around but after correction, still the same problem. I've been digging this hole for a while now trying different things.  If you start with a src in the img object, it will be replaced but only by an empty image.

Comment: Without a url to go by, it's difficult to see.  My only thought would be that the copy/paste code should be outside of the getJSON() function just in case the browser has not yet fully updated the 'bookCover' element?

Answer (score 1):

Without more info - eg, I can't see where the getJSON() function ends or what the URL's are, I can't see what the issue may be (except, perhaps, as in my last comment).

I idea seems ok, as I can replicate it (in a cut-down version of course):

```js
function copyImageSource() {
  let d = document.getElementById("bookCover").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("imgDisp").src = d;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyImageSource();">Get image</button>

<div id="bookCover">https://duckduckgo.com/assets/icons/meta/DDG-icon_256x256.png</div>
<img id="imgDisp" src="">
```

I assume that this is the sort of thing you are trying to achieve?

(javascript -> jquery:

```
let copyPic = $("#bookCover").html();
$("#imgDisp").attr("src", copyPic);
```

)

Version using jquery:

```js
function copyImageSource() {
  let d = $("#bookCover");
  d.html("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=YIx0ngEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api");
  let dCopy = d.html().replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
  $("#imgDisp").attr("src", dCopy);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="copyImageSource();">Get image</button>

<div id="bookCover"></div>

<img id="imgDisp" src="https://www.picsearch.com/images/logo.png"/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I should have included the code just before this:

$("form").submit(
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isbn = $('#ISBN').val();
    var isbn_without_hyphens = isbn.replace(/-/g, "");
    var googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + isbn_without_hyphens;

some example ISBN's would be 9780692306611, 9781785780202, 9781523978717

Comment: np - As long as that snippet was what you are trying to achieve, my first thought is about timing - ie, the browser may not have rendered the bookCover element's HTML by the time the copy/paste is requested.  So, move that part of the code to below the function and see if that helps. Otherwise, the only other thing I can think of is that you have used jquery for most of it, but vanilla javascript for the copy/paste - you could also try changing those two lines to jquery versions as well.

Comment: It took me a while to set it up to include a cut down version of my code to include yours, but it still doesn't work.  It just changes the existing image into a blank space.  I've just seen you're added note so I'll try those ideas now. thanks

Comment: Or, that one of the id's you have entered in the code doesn't relate to an actual html element and, therefore, the code is breaking at that point?

Comment: Blank space - or, "no-image" default icon?

Comment: OK - I got that when I tested my code using the wrong string!  As long as you are happy that the image file does exist, I think one of my previous suggestions may well be the answer.  ie - it's either timing, jquery -v- javascript or missing id's

Comment: If you do an "inspect" on the img, what does it show?  It could be that, whilst the image may exist, the browser can't load it as an image because it requires special access rights.  Thus, whilst the url may be correct, the browser can't access it.

Comment: I've tried moving the code as you say, but no difference. I've checked the id's and everything good.  Could you advice how to change the 'vanilla javascript' to jquery?

Comment: the line "$("#bookCover").html(response.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);" brings down the correct response so I guess no access problem.  Do you know how I could rewrite that line to put it straight into the image object without cutting and pasting? Instead of writing it to a <p> first.

Comment: I don't get errors sadly cos I'm writing code on a pc, in text files on a linux raspberry pi. [smile]

Comment: I've added a bit to the end of my Answer showing the jquery versions for those two lines.

Comment: Blimey - and there's me just using a plain old Windows 10 pc, a browser and a text editor!

Comment: I've updated my Answer to include a version that uses jQuery.  That works as well.

Comment: I've tried your Jquery version.  If I use random images - it works fine, but working with an asp type line eg "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=YIx0ngEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api", then it doesn't work.  So I'm guessing it must be something to do with the data itself.  Even though popping the line into the scr directly works, loading it indirectly via a variable doesn't. Ah well!  Perhaps I can find a way to physically download the cover images and hold them in the dbase.Thanks ever so much for trying to help - very much appreciated

Comment: OK - If I update my local version of my code using that url, I don't see the image either.  The issue is the ampersands.  The copy/paste converts these into `&amp;` which invalidates the url.

Comment: I've updated by Answer - try the second snippet.  It seems to work OK if I replace the `&amp;` 's

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery you can easily do the following:

```
let source = 'https://img.com/image.png';

//to get the image object that has the above just do this:
let img = $('img[src="' + source + '"]');
```

Comment: Wow! How did you find this? I'm amazed.  However, I'm struggling to understand what I have to do.  The problem is there are '&' in the lines I'm using - eg "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=thPBrQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api" - has 4 ampersands. So I need to wrap the $('img...code around the source line and copy that.  Is that right? I'm trying to code that now

Comment: This is very basic jQuery code, and no, dont worry about the ampersands, and just replace what is in source.. and then console.log(img) after the last line i gave you and see what you get.

Comment: I'm so tired now - I think I'm going to have to go to bed.  I think I understand what I need to do. But I have to alter my code before I can test it - and rather than make a big mess I'll have to carry on tomorrow. So grateful for your help. Cheers - big time.

Comment: Try this... 
https://jsfiddle.net/cxLfpahd/,  see I can alert the class of that img tag or do whatever I want to do with it, JUST by grabbing an img by its src content